# An object in array, what dataType?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, back

I want put front to back objet in an array. But i do not see how to do this with dataType.
I want this :

```
"task": [
    {
      "car": "feri",
      "color": "blue"
    }
  ],
  "id_user": 1
```

In my data table i make this :

```
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "task" text[],
```

And in the model this :

```
 task: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.TEXT),
    id_user : DataTypes.INTEGER
```

So when i put in back, in the dataTable i have this :

```
"id": 1,
      "task": [
        "{\"car\":\"feri\",\"color\":\"blue\"}"
      ],
```

Now i see my error, i make text in an array. But i want objet and i do not see how.

How can i make that ?

Thanks for read :)

Comment: I guess on your third code example everything is serialized. Anyhow, could you be much more specific? Are you using sequelize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to store an array of objects then just use JSON or JSONB data type in a DB and `task: DataTypes.JSON` in a model.